# Simplify the following expression. ¬[u ∨ (u ∧ r)] → ¬(r ∧ r)

Tags: propositional-calculus

so far I got:
¬[¬u ∨ (u ∧ r)] V ¬(r ∧ r)

Comment: Do you have any ideas, anything you suspect about the statements? What have you thought?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\neg[u\vee (u \wedge r)] \rightarrow \neg(r\wedge r)$$
$$\neg\neg[u\vee (u \wedge r)]\vee\neg r$$
$$u\vee\neg r$$
$$r \rightarrow u$$

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!